# Exception in initialize TextField

Tags: javafx, textfield

I try initialize a TextField of JavaFX, but when I do it, is throw a Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException, Caused by: Toolkit not initialized. There was a VBox initialized before and nothing happens.

```
private static Node getNumericField(Title title, Numeric annotation) {
        VBox pane = new VBox();
        TextField numericField = new TextField(); // TODO Toolkit not initialized
        Label titleLabel;
        if(title == null) {
            titleLabel = new Label();
        }else{
            titleLabel = new Label(title.title());
        }

        int viewSize = annotation.viewSize();
        numericField.setMaxWidth(viewSize);
        numericField.setMinWidth(viewSize);
        numericField.setPrefWidth(viewSize);

        // TODO Put mask validation here

        pane.getChildren().addAll(titleLabel, numericField);

        return pane;

    }
```

This code is in a Class, being called in a static method: 'run(Class clazz)'.

A waiting!

Comment: Can you check the import. Is it `import javafx.scene.control.TextField` or `import java.awt.TextField`?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what the reason, but it worked when I extends the Application class. Thanks  ItachiUchiha.